# Changing the owner of a directory when username has a . (dot) in it

Tags: terminal, unix

If I enter `whoami` in Terminal.app my id is shown as Abhi.Sri

Now if I do  `chown -R Abhi.Sri /usr/local` it says the user Abhi.Sri is invalid.

Comment: Please copy/paste the full output of both `whoami` and `chown`, details may matter here.

Comment: As I've just verified, usernames with `.` are not a problem for `chown`, so the problem is definitively something else. But we need some more details about your setup to find out where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

I think your short username is malformed. I recommend to rename it to lower case characters (and no special characters except the underscore).

Additionally you would have to use a *sudoers* account (e.g. an admin account) and prepend `sudo` to change ownership of /usr/local since /usr/local is owned by root:wheel. Changing the ownership of /usr/local **and** subsequent items is non-standard and not recommended.

Comment: OS X happily lets you create usernames with dots and in mixed caps, so this is not the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

The terminal might be interpreting the dot ('.') as a wildcard character.

I'm not at my Mac, so I can't test this, but try escaping the '.' with a backslash:

`chown -R Abhi\.Sri /usr/local`

Comment: Can someone explain why this may have been voted down? Obviously I'm new here, and I'd like to know what makes a good answer. I've taken the "get started" tour and checked the help system specifically for what makes a "good" answer.